# I don't know where i am wrong with Js objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am passing props to a component and collecting it with getDerivedStateFromProps which is receiving it but on decomposing it is giving undefined

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log(nextProps.imgData);
        console.log(nextProps.imgData.value);
        if (nextProps.imgData.value[nextProps.index]) {
            return nextState = {
                name: nextProps.imgData.value[nextProps.index],
                fileURL: nextProps.imgData.url[nextProps.index]
            }
        }
        return null
    }
```

for first log it gave output:

```
imgData:{
url: ["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/medkit…=media&token=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"],

valid: true,

value: ["xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-1f45d20ffac3.png"]

}
```

for second it gave:

```
[]
```

can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you post the exact error, which ma help us understand more?

Comment: is `imgData` a normal object passed or does it come from some library ? (*does it work if your put the `.value` in the first log ?*)

Answer (score -1):

I'd try this:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, nextState) {
    let saved = nextProps.imgData;
    console.log(saved);
    console.log(saved.value);
    if (saved.value[nextProps.index]) {
        return nextState = {
            name: nextProps.imgData.value[nextProps.index],
            fileURL: nextProps.imgData.url[nextProps.index]
        }
    }
    return null
}
```